# у меня не работает toString() в javaб в чем проблема

Tags: java

```
public static int getHeight(float latitude, float longitude)
    {

        try
        {

            String fileName = "N" + ((int)latitude).toString() + "E0" + ((int)longitude).toString() + ".hgt";
```

Comment: Вы приводите переменные latitude и longitude к int, и пытаетесь вызвать у них метод.

Comment: метод toString() не работает на примитивах, надо либо использовать String.valueOf() или конкатенацию +"" ... в любом случае смысла нету, try без catch , нет return и возвращаемое значение int, вообще непонятно что тут должно происходить

Comment: Всегда говорите - "у меня не работает", и наблюдайте, догадаются они, что это значит, или нет.

Answer (score 2):

Здесь вообще не нужно вызывать метод `toString` для примитивных типов `float`/`int`, так как они будут преобразованы в строку автоматически

```
String fileName = "N" + ((int)latitude) + "E0" + ((int)longitude)+ ".hgt";
```

Это описано в [`JLS 5.1.11`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11):

> Any type may be converted to type String by *string conversion*.
>
> A value x of primitive type T is first converted to a reference value as if by giving it as an argument to an appropriate class instance creation expression (§15.9):
> ...
> If T is byte, short, or int, then use new Integer(x).
>
> If T is float, then use new Float(x).
>
> This reference value is then converted to type String by *string conversion.*

Comment: Не будет ли в этом случае преобразовано в строку не только примитивы, а вообще всё? А методов у примитивов как бы и нет вовсе?

Answer (score 1):

Если всё таки в дальнейшем придется переобразовать в строку что то подобное то используйте такой пример

```
String fileName = "N" + (Integer.toString((int)latitude)) + "E0" + (Integer.toString((int)longitude)) + ".hgt";
```